# Как правильно дать права на доступ к представлению? Ошибка ORA-00942

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Ламерский вопрос.
Есть схемы `owner1` и `owner2`.

Под пользователем `owner1`  создаю `view` на основе таблиц `owner1.t1`, `owner1.t2`, `owner1.t3`.

Даю пользователю `owner2` права на select из таблиц `owner1.t1`, `owner1.t2`, `owner1.t3`.

Запрос под пользователем `owner2` из указанных таблиц в схеме `owner1` проходит.  А вот на запрос под `owner2` из представления `owner1.view` получаю ошибку:

> ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Надо дать права select на view, а не на таблицы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос далеко не ламерский. Проблема в неполном понимании, зачем нужны представления. Коротко процитирую из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/partitions-views-and-other-schema-objects.html#GUID-15E7AEDB-9A3F-4B31-AD2D-66253CC822E5):

> Views enable you to tailor the presentation of data to different types of users. Views are often used to:
>
> - Provide an additional level of table security by restricting access to a predetermined set of rows or columns of a table
> - Hide data complexity
>
> For example, a single view can be defined with a join, which is a collection of related columns or rows in multiple tables. However, the view hides the fact that this information actually originates from several tables. A query might also perform extensive calculations with table information. Thus, users can query a view without knowing how to perform a join or calculations.

Владелец таблиц с данными (`owner1`) даёт посредством представлений другим пользователям (приложениям) доступ к данных из своих таблиц в том виде и объёме, в котором он считает нужным, но при этом скрывая, как выглядят данные на самом деле и откуда они происходят.

Представление в запросе выполняется с правами его владельца (`owner1`), а не с правами того, кто выполняет запрос (`owner2`). То есть, владелец представления должен дать права *на представление*, но ни в коем случае *не на таблицы*, которые входят в представление.

Как это выглядит на примере. Как `owner1` выполните:

```
create table t1 (id, name, memo) as
    select 1, 't1', 't1 info invisible by others' from dual
/
create table t2 (id, name, memo) as
    select 1, 't2', 't2 info invisible by others' from dual
/
create or replace view v1 (name1, name2, memo) as
    select t1.name, t2.name, 't1,t2 info visible by others'
    from t1 join t2 on t2.id=t2.id;

grant select on v1 to owner2;
```

Теперь `owner2` видит только то, что ему положено:

```
connect owner2/pass@dbsrv/db1

select * from owner1.v1
/
NA NA MEMO
-- -- ----------------------------
t1 t2 t1,t2 info visible by others
```

Но не видит самих таблиц, которые принадлежат `owner1`:

```
 select * from owner1.t1
  2  /
select * from owner1.t1
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```